# C# TCP multiple client issue when two clients run on the same machine

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm new in StackOverflow and I spent a lot of time searching for a solution for my issue and couldn't found any.
So, I want to test a very simple C# server/multiple client application.
It works fine with clients what have different IP addresses. When I start two clients using the same wi-fi, I have the following socket exception on the server `socket.EndReceive` line:

> "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

This is my server code:

```
class Program {

        private static Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private static byte[] bufferPubblico = new byte[4096];

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, *port*));
            server.Listen(1);
            server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
            Socket socket = server.EndAccept(AR);
            Console.WriteLine("A new client connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(bufferPubblico, 0, bufferPubblico.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR) {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(bufferPubblico, dataBuf, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Text Received: " + text);

            socket.BeginReceive(bufferPubblico, 0, bufferPubblico.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        }
    }
```

And this is my client code:

```
class Program
{
    private static Socket socket;
    private static byte[] bufferPubblico = new byte[4096];

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string ip = Console.ReadLine();
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), *port*);
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Connect(localEndPoint);
        socket.BeginReceive(bufferPubblico, 0, bufferPubblico.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);

        while (true) {
            string messaggio = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messaggio);
            socket.Send(data);
        }
    }

    static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR) {
        Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
        byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(bufferPubblico, dataBuf, received);

        string messaggio = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
        Console.WriteLine("Text Received: " + messaggio);

        socket.BeginReceive(bufferPubblico, 0, bufferPubblico.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
    }
}
```

So, my question is Why when I connect two clients sharing the same IP I get the above exception?

P.S. The two clients that generate the exception have the same IP of the server, i.e. they are started on the same computer.

Post edit:
I solved my issue adding the

> Socket.Close()

to close the connection between server and client before ending the application.
I supposed it wasn't so important, but the tcp connection must be closed, otherwise some exceptions occur.

Comment: the code you posted works fine on my computer. You do have a bug: your server code shares the `bufferPubblico` field with every connection. As long as the two clients don't send data at the same time, this won't be a problem, but it would cause an issue if they did. You should make sure to dedicate a unique buffer to each client. If you want help with your problem, please improve the question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: do you really need to poll the socket like that? can you check if the socket is available and if it isn't, try another port?

Comment: @terribletp: there's no polling in the code that the OP posted.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the comment. In my complete project there is an user class in the server code with all the information and a byte[] databuf for each user, but the exception subsist.

Comment: Isn't net code fun? I would open an endpoint just for clients to register, and then allocate a connection to them from some kind of pool.

Comment: Regardless, your [mcve] should be free of all known bugs. Otherwise, you cause other people to waste their time commenting on or even posting answers addressing bugs that have nothing to do with what your actual problem is. Telling me in the comments that the bug is intentional is not nearly as useful as you editing your post so that it has code without that bug.

Comment: Someone suggested me to Bind each client with a different port, but I think it's impossible because I have a forward port in my gateway for this application.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I only said that I have an issue with this code and I not resolved it yet

Comment: Yeah you would have to bind a range of ports. Most if not all routers should allow this

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard but I don't know why sometimes my code works and sometimes not (i.e. the exception occurs)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN have an excellent guide on how to create an asynchronous socket server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example).

Following this tutorial will certainly help with your en-devours into socket programming(it is copy/paste-able code).

A thing to note with the `Socket` API, there is a chance not all data is received in `OnReceive` and as such requires you to check for a string terminator, MSDN uses the example of appending `<EOF>` to the end of each string you send.

Give that [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) a good read and see if it doesn't fix your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.